# Скопировать все папки с одного репозитория на gitHub в другой

Tags: веб-программирование, git, github

Есть репозиторий на GitHub, содержащий проект. Я создал новый репозиторий и хочу скопировать все папки и файлы с прошлого репозитория в новый, при этом оставив старый без изменений.

Comment: Ну, открыть любимый файловый менеджер и скопировать из одной папочки в другую? Потом закоммитить и запушить

Comment: `git remote add new git://new.remote.com/repository.git; git push new branchX:branchY` -- всё. Дальше возможны всякие оптимизации типа убийства истории (полный squash), заливка не всего подряд и т.д. @andreymal, а вы с Git когда-нибудь работали?

Comment: @0andriy и какой смысл проводить такие сложнохитровыдуманные комбинации с remote-push-squash, если абсолютно то же самое можно получить просто скопировав папочки через файловый менеджер? Работаю с Git семь лет и предпочитаю не делать лишних телодвижений, в отличие от вас.

Comment: @andreymal, по-моему, вы как раз описали довольно сложный путь. Не говоря уже о *гибкости* решения...

Comment: @0andriy преждевременные оптимизации есть зло. Вот когда гибкости простого и понятного файлового менеджера перестанет хватать, тогда уже можно начинать задумываться о чём-то другом. А ваши команды, кстати, ещё и замусоривают локальную копию репозитория лишним remote и, вероятно, лишней веткой (если делать-таки squash) — я сомневаюсь, что это то, что хотел автор.

Comment: @andreymal, zOMG, ну хорошо, вы победили!